# Вывести на консоль json array как текст

Tags: javascript, jquery

Имеется код:

```
/* Добавляем в массив */
var Array = [];
$('.service-item').each(function() {
    Array.push({
        'title': $(this).data('original-title'),
        'description': $(this).data('content')
    });
});
```

При `console.log(Array.toString());` выводит: `[object Object],[object Object]`.

Как вывести текст, а не объекты?

Answer (score 4):

берем `json`
существует [`console.table`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Console/table) которая выводит инфу в таблице. очень удобно по крайней мере для меня. Чтобы распарсить `json` используем [`JSON.parse(json)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse)

```
let json = '[{"title":"title1","description":"description1"},{"title":"title2","description":"description2"}]'
console.table(JSON.parse(json));
```

Пример работы функции в Chrome:

> [image]

Answer (score 2):

Можно вместо вызова метода [`toString`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/toString) у массива:

```
console.log(array.toString());
```

использовать метод [`JSON.stringify()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify), передав в него массив в качестве параметра:

```
console.log(JSON.stringify(array));
```

сниппет:

```js
let array = [{
    title: 'title1',
    description: 'description1'
  },
  {
    title: 'title2',
    description: 'description2'
  }
];
console.log(JSON.stringify(array));
```

Кстати, переменные лучше называть так, чтобы они начинались с маленькой буквы, и не стоит использовать в качестве имён переменных существующие идентификаторы, вроде [`Array`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array) или [`String`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String).